# Hosted UI not returning token on mobile devices

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth, amazon-cognito

I'm using AWS [Cognito hosted UI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-app-integration.html).

I successfully logging in and receive jwt token back when I'm signing in from a desktop computer, I'm using response type as token and check the Implicit grant in the Cognito console.

```js
`<#cognito.domain#>/login?response_type=token&client_id=<#my_clieny)id#>&redirect_uri=<#redirect_uri#>`
```

But for some reason when I'm logging in from my iPhone or iPad, I successfully logged in in the Hosted ui but the redirect uri not receiving the token (The desktop computer does receive the token).

I also tried in incognito mode with chrome(on my iPhone) but no luck.

any thoughts will be welcome.

Thanks